# Show a semantic-ui-react popup without onclick of button or anchor tag : React+Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui-react

Trying to bring a popup saying "No Data Found" if there is no data from the backend API. I am unable to achieve this. 
Help would be appreciated.
Here I am using a fetch call to fetch the data, If there is data then set the state object else set the modalOpen boolean flag to true. But it does not seem like working. It is showing up a blank screen.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Modal from 'semantic-ui-react';

interface IState{
  modalOpen: boolean;
  data: [];
}

export default class Test extends React.Component<{},{}> {

   constructor(props:any){
     super(props);
     this.state = { modalOpen: false , data: [] }
   }

   handleOpen = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: true })

   handleClose = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: false }) 

   async componentDidMount(){
      try {       
             let data = await fetch('/api/fetch')
             let res =  await data.json();
             if(res.length>0){  
                     this.setState({ data: json }, modalOpen: false)
              }
              else if(res.length == 0 ) {
                       this.setState({ modalOpen:true})
              }
              else {
                       this.setState({ modalOpen:false})
              }
     }
     catch(e){
         console.log('Error', e.message);
     }
   }

   render()
   {
     return(
            <Modal
               trigger= {this.state.modalOpen}
               open={this.state.modalOpen}
               onClose={this.handleClose}
               basic
               size='small'
            />
            <Modal.Content>
              <h3>No Data</h3>
           </Modal.Content>
           //Displaying results part is not shown here
     )
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems like it's not relates to typescript because if it does, it should not pass the transpilation, not to fail in run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried leaving the trigger attribute on the Modal element away? As far as I know this attribute should reference a valid JSX element like a button or something.

Something like this:

```
<Modal
   open={this.state.modalOpen}
   onClose={this.handleClose}
   basic
   size='small'
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.setState({ data: json }` to `this.setState({ data: res.data }`

check response either res or res.data depends what your server returns..?

Comment: Jacob, There is no issue with setState . I just  have to implement a popup when  there is no data from back end